# Create new tensorflow image classification module using tensorflow hub

Tags: tensorflow-hub

I'm new in tensorflow, i am trying to create new image classification module, I tried below example using tensorflow hub. but its not created. Is any simple example for create image classification module

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np

def module_fn():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
    layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 200)
    layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 100)
    outputs = dict(default=layer2, hidden_activations=layer1)
    # Add default signature.
    hub.add_signature(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

spec = hub.create_module_spec(module_fn)
module=hub.Module(spec)
with tf.Graph().as_default():
      module=hub.Module('new_test_module')
      test=module(np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, 100)))
      with tf.Session() as session:
      img=session.run(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TensorFlow Hub**'s [image classification modules](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-classification) are a collection of examples that showcase how to use model components. To create an image classification component yourself, you can check out the [*Creating a New Module*](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/creating) section of the **TensorFlow Hub API guide**.

**Example utilization:**

> To define a new module, a publisher calls `hub.create_module_spec()` with a function `module_fn`. This function constructs a graph representing the module's internal structure, using `tf.placeholder()` for inputs to be supplied by the caller. Then it defines signatures by calling `hub.add_signature(name, inputs, outputs)` one or more times.

```
def module_fn():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
    layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 200)
    layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 100)
    outputs = dict(default=layer2, hidden_activations=layer1)

    # Add default signature.
    hub.add_signature(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
spec = hub.create_module_spec(module_fn)
```

> The result of `hub.create_module_spec()` can be used, instead of a path, to instantiate a module object within a particular TensorFlow graph. In such case, there is no checkpoint, and the module instance will use the variable initializers instead.